# Why is my Android Emulator appearing and disappearing?

Tags: android-studio, android-virtual-device

I'm learning to use Android Studio. I'm following this tutorial (https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app)

I'm running into an issue where my AVD appears and then immediately disappears. Initially, the AVD indicates that it is "Resetting for Cold Boot Emulator Engine Failed." I stop seeing this issue when I edit the AVD Manager to use Cold Boot instead of Quick Boot.

Now, the AVD appears and does not indicate any error. It just crashes. Is there something that I'm missing?

Additionally, I remember that when I first tried to open up a AVD, there was an alert saying that Riot Vanguard is incompatible with Android Studio. I've since deleted Riot Vanguard, rebooted my machine, and reinstalled Android Studio; Still no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try deleting the AVD and reinstalling if that doesn't work check for updates in

Tools -> SDK Manager -> SDK Tools -> In that look for Android emulator and see whether there's an update

Comment: Thank you. I was able to resolve the issue by downloading the "Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) from SDK Tools.

Comment: Glad that it helped :)

Comment: Intel® HAXM installation failed. To install Intel® HAXM follow the instructions found at: https://github.com/intel/haxm/wiki/Installation-Instructions-on-Windows